# Serivce of Elasticsearch is failed

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, elastic

/etc/elasticsearch have deleted by me accidentally.Now, when I run the command(sudo systemctl start elasticsearch
) to enable service of elasticsearch than the following error show.

> Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

and by getting configuration of elasticsearch to run command(sudo nano /etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml
) the following error generate.

> Directory '/etc/elasticsearch' does not exist

kindly help me.
your help is really appreciate for me!

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall Elasticsearch and it will re-create the missing files and directory for you.

Comment: I will reinstall it several time but it doesn't make dir etc/